# Connecting laravel running on google cloud app engine to google cloud sql database

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to my google cloud SQL database from my Laravel files which are in Google App Engine but I get the error shown in the screenshot below. I have my username, password and all required details in my .yaml file. What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my hostname. I was using localhost instead of my SQL instance's IP.